# Importance of language models when given simple instruction to a Robot

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, language-models

Do I really need a transformer-based language model if I want to instruct a robot very simple task?

Suppose I give an instruction like *"Go to the right and pick up the book from the table"*.

I am confused because the language models are generative but the above instruction is pretty straightforward and the robot does not need to infer anything from the instruction.